# Can I make my website's resources private?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, hosting

I want to make my site's resources like images etc. become private and can only be loaded by local files on my hosting. can someone tell me how, please

Comment: Question is what you mean by "private" and "loaded by local"... Do they have to be accessible via an external request at all or not? If not, then place them _outside_ your http host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder, if yes, then additionally use a routing script to access such resources which allows you to implement whatever restriction you desire.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a seperate folder for your images, create a .htaccess file inside the folder where you have the images and add the following to that .htaccess file:

```
Require local #Make sure there is no file in the directory
```

To hide most images in all directories, add this to the root .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpeg|jpg|png|webp|gif)$">
Require local
</FilesMatch>
```

I prefer the second one for its flexibility.

Or, if you have root access (if you are in a VPS/or on your own server), then use the following:

Open httpd.conf or apache2.conf (either of those), and add the following:

```
<Directory "/path/to/directory/with/images">
Require local
</Directory>
```

Or if the directory with the images also contains files which need to be public, do:

```
<Directory "/path/to/directory/with/images">
<FilesMatch "\.(jpeg|jpg|png|webp|gif)$">
Require local
</FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

Or, you can just move the image files out of the DOCUMENT_ROOT (@arkascha's idea)